# Wordpress if is in category for single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a custom css class to my blog to change the color of the header for each category in the posts list page so i tried to use this code for changing the color of the category number 6 in my single.php :

```
<?php if ( in_category( '6' ) ) { ?>
<header style="background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,173,0,.75),rgba(255,173,0,.75)),url('<?php $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id ); echo $post_thumbnail_url; ?>');" class="cat">
<?php } else {?>
<header style="background: linear-gradient(rgba(25,100,126,.75),rgba(25,100,126,.75)),url('<?php $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id ); echo $post_thumbnail_url; ?>');" class="cat">
<?php} ?>
```

I tried to use with :

```
in_category( 6 )
```

and also with :

```
in_category( 'NAME' )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't write `if(in_category(6)`

do:

```
if (in_category('city'))
```

or whatever your category is that you're checking for

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not in `The Loop` while checking category in header. You must be either in loop to check that or you must pass also post ID to the method like `in_category($categoryId, $postId)`.

Comment: @NateBeers See doc page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category, `Prior to v2.7, this function could only be used in the WordPress Loop. As of 2.7, the function can be used anywhere if it is provided a post ID or post object.`

Comment: tried ` if ( in_category('GRAPHIC DESIGN'),the_ID())` is it what i have to do ? I tried also with the ID 6 with or without the '' it's not working :/ I'm just after the `<div class="post-content">`

Comment: The first example shows that it is not necessary to provide a `$post->ID`

Comment: Don't use all caps unless your category actually is all caps

Comment: It should work with ID anyway, so something else is wrong

Comment: @Playz Is the post exactly in that category or its' child category? Check the output of `get_the_category_list()`

Comment: Tried to put the title of the category exactly with the same caps, the post is exactly in that category, a category called Graphic design with the graphic-design ID. I made a mistake i used the tag_id=6 of the category's url. But even if with the correct ID it's not working

Comment: Even if i don't put anything in the if i have a php error, maybe my error is in the else php code ?

Comment: Tried with <?php if (in_category('graphic-design')) {echo 'test'; }?> and it works, it displays the test... So i have another problem i will find it thank you very much for your help @ArmanP and nate beers !